# Некорректный JSON на сайте

Tags: python, json, парсер

Возникла проблема при парсинге сайта. Не получается перевести строку в dict, т.к. ключи у самого JSON-объекта без кавычек ("). Можно ли как-то исправить эту проблему?

Вот пример некорректного JSON:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Просили текст со скрина: `"{art_id: '63547987',author_id: '27013571',alt: '13 ключей к пониманию себя, своего окружения и своих отношений',author: 'Анна Просветова',type: '0',mem: 'text',drm: '0',price: '225.00',available: '1',can_preorder: '0',main_book_id: '',promo_price: '225.00'}"`

Comment: Это не json, это javascript

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, как конвертировать объект javascript в dict? (или сначала js-объект в объект JSON, а уже после - dict)

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос текст со скриншота.

Comment: @КириллМалышев сделано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
import ast
js_obj="{art_id: '63547987',author_id: '27013571',alt: '13 ключей к пониманию себя, своего окружения и своих отношений',author: 'Анна Просветова',type: '0',mem: 'text',drm: '0',price: '225.00',available: '1',can_preorder: '0',main_book_id: '',promo_price: '225.00'}"
quote_keys_regex = r'([\{\s,])(\w+)(:)'
dct_in_str = re.sub(quote_keys_regex, r'\1"\2"\3', js_obj)
dct = ast.literal_eval(dct_in_str)
```

Регулярное выражение из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027831/7485582) [@chrisb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3657742/chrisb). В других ответах того же вопроса можете посмотреть варианты с исползованием сторонних библиотек.

Comment: А eval можно как-то заменить?

Comment: Вы беспокоитесь за безопасность? `literal_eval` не может выполнять произвольный код, а только разбирает стандартные объекты, такие как списки, словари и т.д.