# python json без кавычек

Tags: python, json

Попадается json, в котором значения могут быть без кавычек. Например `{"key": value}` или `{"key": true}`.
Не получается преобразовать так, что бы загрузить `json.loads()`.

Реальный json на гист: https://gist.github.com/andreyru02/d10d0c30287f193206892b5a4252b182

Comment: {"key": true} не надо преобразовывает, и так работает. В другом случае зависит от того, что там у вас за value. Приведите пример реальных данных и код, которым пытаетесь загрузить

Comment: сбросьте пример json, что какой трейсбек у вас?

Comment: может вот это помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274386/209304

Comment: Покажите ваш конкретный `json`, возможно совсем не в этом дело. `true`, `false` и числа могут быть без кавычек, это вообще не проблема, это корректный `json`.

Comment: @Эникейщик, добавил в описание реальный json.

Comment: json по ссылке сломанный из-за шести объектов `undefined` — если их закавычить, то всё становится нормально. Лучше всего отправить авторам этого json сообщение об ошибке, чтобы они исправили на своей стороне эти undefined

Comment: @andreymal это json с html сайта донора парсинга, я думаю они не обрадуются, если им сказать, чтобы поправили json, так как их не удобно парсить))

Comment: Ну тогда можно попробовать прямо в строке заменить ":undefined" на ":null" и после этого грузить как обычный json

Comment: @CrazyElf да, уже от безысходности рассматривал этот вариант, только это решение на раз. Можно предположить, что на другой странице, будет другое слово без кавычек.)

Comment: @andreyru02 Да нет, я думаю другого ничего не будет. Это явно из `JavaScript` так небрежно генерили, а там кроме `undefined` вряд ли что такого может вылезти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае это не корректный `json`. То есть он не сооветствует формату.

#### Что можно сделать?

1. Отказаться от работы с интерфейсами, которые не следуют протоколу
2. Обрабатывать входящий `json`, как обычную строку при помощи методов строки. Очень трудоемкий процесс, поскольку все сущности нужно будет переопределять заново. Например, `null -> None` или булевы значения `true -> True`, `false -> False`. Разбить на пары ключ значения можно через метод `split(",")`, а затем получившийся результат, который есть список, разбить по знаку `:` и дальше обрабатывать как строки, так или иначе преобразовывая в нужный тип данных
3. Обратиться к документации API, и попробовать найти метод, который возвращает готовый json-документ. Встречается такое, что есть отдельная конечная точка, которая дает возможность загрузить json (встречается в API, где есть несколько форматов скачивания данных и формат может указываться, как параметр в URL конечной точки)

**UPD данные от ТС**

О чем в принципе и была речь. У вас не валидный `json`. Он не может содержать значения `undefined`. Почитать на англ можно [здесь](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/).

#### Как исправить

Заменить `undefined` на `null`

```py
json_str = """
"cfg": {
        "buildName": "ssr@release-2022-11-02t15-18-38z",
        "staticBaseUrl":
......
"""

json_str = json_str.replace('undefined', 'null')
```

Следом вы получите следующее исключение, которое касается экранированных кавычек.

#### Как исправить

Использовать `raw`-string.

```py
json_str = r'%s' %json_str
json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
```

После этого json модуль ошибок не выдает

Comment: Почему вдруг некорректный? В джейсоне true и false как раз и пишутся с маленькой буквы. Модуль json автоматически заменяте true на True и false на False. Поэтому тут ничего переопределять не надо. Что касается первого примера, то если value там просто пример чего-то, скорее всего числа, то тоже ничего не нужно заменять.

Comment: @Эникейщик но будет выкидывать исключение если хоть одна сущность не формат. Следовательно, у нас остается строка, которая содержит значние `true`, как строковая последовательноть и никак переделать с помощью `json` модуля не получится. Пока нет примера данных, все равно только догадки и предположения

Comment: @Эникейщик я встречал такое, что конечная точка возращает строку, которая мимикрирует под `json` и чтобы ты не делал, необходимо было писать обработку, а также обращаться,  в поддержку API, что у них там не корректные данные. Для меня вот [эта таблица](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) более, чем понятна. Но вопрос кажется не об этом

Comment: @Dmitry добавил в описание реальный json

Comment: @Dmitry Пока что, как времянку просто заменил `undefined` и естественно json загрузил. Но потом, как время будет нужно все таки написать обработчик таких невалидных json.)

Comment: @andreyru02 я написал бы в поддержку АПИ, чтобы они хотя бы знали, что у них не верно генерируется json.